# How to make this time logic

Tags: c#, asp.net

From the store i am getting 
open time and close time
i can get open time  14(just integer not time format) oclock today 
and close time 2(just integer not time format) oclock tomorrw

I want to form a time list
that starts from the 14+45mint then 15 mint interval untill tomorrw 2 oclock
How can i make this.

I am trying it something like this, but i am unable to fix interval for next day.

```
ePOSEntities db = new ePOSEntities();
int d = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
StoreTiming st = (from s in db.StoreTimings 
                  where s.Week_Day == d 
                  select s).FirstOrDefault();
var time = DateTime.Now;
DateTime OpenDtim = Convert.ToDateTime(st.OpenTime);
DateTime CloseDtim = Convert.ToDateTime(st.CloseTime).AddDays(1);

for (DateTime x = OpenDtim; x <= CloseDtim; x++) { 

}
```

Comment: Is "open time" always "today" and "close time" always "tomorrow"?

Comment: that may the same day as well thats y i am stuck on fixing how to form the intervals.

Answer (score 3):

```
// parse your 'openTime' and 'closeTime'
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

DateTime step = openTime.AddMinutes(45);

while (step<closeTime) {
   list.Add(step);
   step = step.AddMinutes(15);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the AddMinutes adds it to the DateTime object, which understands things like midnight and next days.

Comment: oh is that so it will understand for tomorrow as well, and will work for for same day settings too, thats what i confuse on , thanks a lot.

Comment: regardless when `openTime` and `closeTime` are, as long as `closeTime` is at least 45 minutes after `openTime` this should work. `DateTime` is really one long number (Ticks) wrapped in code that calculates the actual minutes, hours, months, day of week etc, so when you add some minutes it just adds to that long number

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [DateTime.AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx)

```
 List<DateTime> dtList = new List<DateTime>();
 OpenDtim = OpenDtim.AddMinutes(45)
 dtList.Add(OpenDtim);
 while (OpenDtim < CloseDtim)
 {
    OpenDtim = OpenDtim.AddMinutes(15);
    dtList.Add(OpenDtim);

 }
return dtList;
```